How to configure Docker permissions for container to write to a volume as a non-root user?
I have my web application deployed in a couple of Docker containers, and for file uploads I need to be able to write to the filesystem. The application is proxied through Nginx running on the same server (but not in a container) which passes the uploaded files to users.
The problem I have is around permissions - Docker containers run as root by default, but if my container writes a file as root, it can't be read by Nginx which uses the www-data user.
I am using a Distroless container and building from their "nonroot" variant which is described thus: The "nonroot" images are configured to default to executing as a normal user account called "nonroot", with user ID 65532.
On my server I have added a user called nonroot, given them the uid 65532 and added them to the www-data group. I can su to that user and write files to the public folder.
In my docker-compose I have the following:
services:
   my-api:
      image: my-api
      ports:
         - 8080:8080
      user: 65532:65532
      volumes: 
         - /var/www/my-web-application/public-files:/public-files

The container starts correctly and runs fine in other regards, but when I try to upload a file I get the following message from the API: Failed to create /public-files/user/1234: mkdir /public-files/user/1234: permission denied
My understanding is that the corresponding user inside and outside the container should automatically match up (so uid 65532 in the container should be treated as uid 65532 outside the container) but that does not appear to be happening.
If I do not use the nonroot version of the container and the code runs as root it can successfully write to the volume, but it writes it as root and then Nginx can't read it.
What do I need to change in order to be able to write from my Docker container to the filesystem in a way that can be served by Nginx?
Edit: After more investigation it seems that what I'm trying to do may not be possible with this configuration - any files created by the Docker container will be created explicitly with the 65532:65532 permissions. Although I can create files as the user whose uid is 65532 from outside the folder, that is because the user has group permission to those folders. Setting user and group permissions directly the way that happens inside the container means that even if the permissions are configured so that Nginx can read and docker can write, Nginx cannot read what Docker has written because it sets both user and group. If I want to do things this way it looks as though I will have to build my own version of the noroot container with the uid/gid matching my www-data user on my server, which isn't really in keeping with the transferability I'm aiming to facilitate with containerisation.
The other way I can see to solve the problem is to put my Nginx proxy in a nonroot container referencing the same volume - that should work fine and although it feels a bit stupid to have nginx behind nginx on my test server I assume I can use that container as my user-facing HTTP server for production.
If there is another way to do this, I'd love to hear about it, but I think I now have a grasp of the reason that it doesn't work as it is.

It's been a while I haven't done that. But you might want to check the SELinux labeling on the ''source volume'' /public-files in your case. I believe there was a -z flag for Docker volume mounts options as well. Howerver, not sure how it does translate in a Dockerfile. This is by no mean a solution but at least something you might want to look at.

Can you please update your question with the output of running ls -ld /var/www/my-web-application/public-files on the host, the output of running ls -ld /public-files inside the container, and the output of running id in the container, and the output of running ps -fe inside the container? Alternately, please update your question to include a minimal, reproducible example so that we have all the parts necessary to reproduce this problem.


My understanding is that the corresponding user inside and outside the container should automatically match up but that does not appear to be happening.

Your understanding is incorrect. If you want a bind mount to be writable by a user with id 65532, then you need to ensure those permissions before starting the container (for example, by running chown 65532 /var/www/my-web-application/public-files).
There are a few ways to manage things so that this is less of a problem.
One options is to separate your application's read-write and read-only data. If /var/www/my-web-application/public-files contains pre-existing content, then modify your application to read content from /public-files, but write data to e.g. /home/nonroot. Given a compose file like this:
volumes:
  app-data:

services:
   my-api:
      image: my-api
      ports:
         - 8080:8080
      volumes: 
        - /var/www/my-web-application/public-files:/public-files
        - app-data:/home/nonroot

The directory /home/nonroot will be writeable by uid 65532, because when you mount a volume on a directory it inherits the ownership of that directory.

You don't have to use /home/nonroot; I just picked that because it already exists and has the correct ownership. You could create an alternate directory in your Dockerfile as long as you ensure that it is owned by the appropriate uid.
Here's one example of doing this, in which we copy /home/nonroot into a new location by using a multi-stage build:
FROM docker.io/debian:12 AS build
FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian12:nonroot AS nonroot

FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian12:nonroot

COPY --from=nonroot /home /var/

COPY --from=build /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
COPY --from=build /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 /lib/
COPY --from=build /bin/dash /usr/bin/id /usr/bin/ls /usr/bin/sleep /bin

CMD ["/bin/sh"]

This gets us:
$ docker run -it --rm my-api ls -ld /var/nonroot /home/nonroot
drwx------. 1 65532 65532 0 Jan  1  1970 /home/nonroot
drwx------. 1 65532 65532 0 Jan  1  1970 /var/nonroot


When you say I need to ensure these permissions before starting to container, do you mean ensure that the folder in the host is writeable by user 65532?

That's correct.

Right, I have done that and I can su to that user and write files from the OS outside the container, but although I have confirmed that the container is running with the same user and group id using docker container inspect I still get the same permissions error when I try to create anything from inside the container.

Is your system running selinux (do you have the getenforce command and does it report Enforcing)?

It is just regular Debian - this is a basic testing VPS, no SELinux there.

I've asked for some additional information on your question to see if we can figure this out.
